# cannot get baseboard serial number in nodejs

Tags: node.js, system-information

I am running ubuntu in vmware. I am trying to get the baseboard serial number.

```
var si = require("systeminformation");
console.log(si.baseboard().serial);
```

It return undefined. Is the problem in my code? Or the problem is ubuntu is running in vmware?

Answer (score 0):

You can see [here](https://github.com/sebhildebrandt/systeminformation/blob/571c0e136c74f1940386e66c8c0910e5028dfa83/lib/system.js#L365) in the `systeminformation` source that it's reading the file `/sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id/board_serial` (if running `dmidecode -t 2 2>/dev/null` fails).

If you `cat /sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id/board_serial` in your shell (if it even exists), what do you get?

If it's empty or non-existent, then the data isn't provided by your environment.

Comment: Thanks. /sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id/board_serial does not exist. And I find the reason the file does not exist is that it is a virtual machine. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

To complete AKX answer, `si.baseboard()` returns a *Promise* (since [v3](https://github.com/sebhildebrandt/systeminformation#promises)), so you have to do something like this:

```
si.baseboard().then(el => console.log(el.serial))
```

or, if you want to stick with callback syntax

```
si.baseboard(el => { console.log(el.serial) })
```

Note for me, it returns an empty string if I launch the script as a regular user. I can display the serial number only if I launch it as root.

Answer (score 0):

I find that I can use serial-number to get an unique number even on virtual machine.

```
var serialNumber = require('serial-number');

serialNumber(function (err, value) {
 console.log(value);
});
```

Comment: _serial-number_ is based on _dmidecode_ so you can probably do. Note I have to deal also with access right with this package on my system (not a vm).

Comment: Do you know how i can get the value and store it in other variable outside the function? I tried different method but not work